# Unable to create converter for class, requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered

Tags: android, retrofit, moshi

I have a class (StickerDto) used to hold data coming in from an API call, which includes a list of another class (Sticker):

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
class StickerDto(
        @Json (name = "totalAnimatedStickers") val total: Int,
        @Json(name = "pages") val pages: Int,
        @Json(name = "data") val stickers: List<Sticker>

)



@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
class Sticker(
        @Json(name = "name") val name: String,
        @Json(name = "id") val id: String,
        @Json(name = "stickerData") val stickerData: JSONObject,
        var isSelected:Boolean = false
)
```

Note that the data type for "stickerData" attribute in the Sticker class is of type JSONObject, which is what is sent from the backend. My problem began when I switch it to that data type from being of type String. The reason I did *that* is because I have a custom Json adapter that skips the JSON object because it's expecting a string.

```
internal class SkipBadElementsListAdapter(private val elementAdapter: JsonAdapter<Any?>) : JsonAdapter<List<Any?>>() {

    object Factory : JsonAdapter.Factory {
     
    override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): List<Any?>? {
        val result = mutableListOf<Any?>()
        reader.beginArray()
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            try {
                val peeked = reader.peekJson()
                result.add(elementAdapter.fromJson(peeked))
            } catch (e: JsonDataException) {
                Timber.w(e, "Item skipped while parsing:")
            }
            reader.skipValue()
        }
        reader.endArray()
        return result
    }

}
```

The tricky part is that this app is designed so that all API calls use the same Retrofit client, which is built using this adapter:

```
  private fun createNewUserApiClient(authRefreshClient: AuthRefreshClient,
                                       preferencesInteractor: PreferencesInteractor): UserApiClient {
        val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
                .add(SkipBadElementsListAdapter.Factory)
             

        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
                .baseUrl(Interactors.apiEndpoint)
                .build()
                .create(UserApiClient::class.java)
    }
```

Basically my question is this:

Is there anyway to modify these classes that will allow for the API call to return the list of Sticker objects that have that JSON object as an attribute, without disrupting the other API calls using this Retrofit instance? Attempting the call now gives me the error in the title:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.weare8.android.data.StickerDto

 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Platform class java.util.LinkedHashMap in java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with me :

```
val Moshi = Moshi.Builder()
        .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .build()
```

Use moshi to creat Retrofit:

.addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))

Dependencies (gradle):

```
  //Moshi
    def moshi_version = "1.8.0"
    kapt("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:$moshi_version")
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:$moshi_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-adapters:$moshi_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$moshi_version"
```